# How to get rid of xmlns="" in a result of xslt transformation? See inside

Tags: perl, xslt

I'm trying to make ONIX from my XML. Here is the XSL file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" mediatype="application/xml">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:template match="books">
    <xsl:variable name="SentDate"><xsl:value-of select="translate(@timestamp,'- :','')" /></xsl:variable>
<ONIXMessage xmlns="http://www.editeur.org/onix/2.1/reference">
    <Header>
        <FromCompany>MyCompany</FromCompany>
        <ToCompany>Google Play</ToCompany>
        <SentDate><xsl:value-of select="substring($SentDate,1,string-length($SentDate) - 2)" /></SentDate>
    </Header>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</ONIXMessage>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="books/book">
    <Product>
        <RecordReference><xsl:value-of select="@id" /></RecordReference>
    </Product>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the XML for transformation:

```
<books xmlns:l="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" timestamp="2013-05-27 22:03:02">
  <book id="1">...</book>
  <book id="2">...</book>
  <book id="3">...</book>
</books>
```

And here is the result of transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ONIXMessage xmlns="http://www.editeur.org/onix/2.1/reference" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<Header>
  <FromCompany>MyCompany</FromCompany>
  <ToCompany>Google Play</ToCompany>
  <SentDate>201305272203</SentDate>
</Header>
<Product xmlns="">
  <RecordReference>1</RecordReference>
</Product>
<Product xmlns="">
  <RecordReference>2</RecordReference>
</Product>
<Product xmlns="">
  <RecordReference>3</RecordReference>
</Product>
</ONIXMessage>
```

So, the question is: how to get rid of those **xmlns=""** in all Product nodes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks everyone, just got what was wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I got the idea how to fix it. I should declare the same xmlns (http://www.editeur.org/onix/2.1/reference) for all my templates, so that every element would be in that namespace.